# Download Large File Using Web API Returning OutOfMemoryException

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I've tried using numerous questions/answers on SO - but can't seem to overcome the `OutOfMemoryException` I receive when trying to download a 200MB zip file via the web api.

I've drastically simplified my code in order to test:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExportReports(OrderExportFilter filterJson)
    {

        var filename = "C:\\pdftemp\\1128d0ff-a4b7-440d-9e3b-dd152445eb62.zip";

        var fileStream = File.OpenRead(filename);

        var content = new StreamContent(fileStream, 4096);

        resp.Content = content;

        resp.Content.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/pdf");
        resp.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
        {
            FileName = "OrdersExport.pdf"
        };

        return resp;
     }
```

This is just one of many way's I've attempted to download the zip file, I've also [referenced this link](https://www.strathweb.com/2013/01/asynchronously-streaming-video-with-asp-net-web-api/) and duplicated the code to no avail.

I'm at a loss as to what I'm doing incorrectly to enable large zip files to be downloaded.

**Update:** Per request in comments i've tried using "application/octet-stream" instead - still no luck - same error.

Also - one more thing to note - when i download smaller zip files using this code it works fine, it just seems once the file is too large is starts to bomb.

**Exception Update:**

I was able to pull the exception details:

```
    {
        "Message": "An error has occurred.",
        "ExceptionMessage": "Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.",
        "ExceptionType": "System.OutOfMemoryException",
        "StackTrace": "   at System.IO.MemoryStream.set_Capacity(Int32 value)\r\n   at System.IO.MemoryStream.EnsureCapacity(Int32 value)\r\n   at System.IO.MemoryStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)\r\n   at System.IO.Compression.DeflateStream.WriteDeflaterOutput(Boolean isAsync)\r\n   at System.IO.Compression.DeflateStream.PurgeBuffers(Boolean disposing)\r\n   at System.IO.Compression.DeflateStream.Dispose(Boolean disposing)\r\n   at System.IO.Stream.Close()\r\n   at System.IO.Compression.GZipStream.Dispose(Boolean disposing)\r\n   at System.IO.Stream.Close()\r\n   at System.IO.Stream.Dispose()\r\n   at System.Net.Http.Extensions.Compression.Core.Compressors.BaseCompressor.<Compress>d__4.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Net.Http.Extensions.Compression.Core.Models.CompressedContent.<SerializeToStreamAsync>d__4.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Owin.HttpMessageHandlerAdapter.<BufferResponseContentAsync>d__13.MoveNext()"
    }
```

Comment: And why is it POST and not GET (just curious)?

Comment: because we are posting over filters that define the type of data returned

Comment: On which line is this exception happening exactly ?

Comment: This code should work fine. Is it exact code which produces exception? What is stack trace? How do you call this code?

Comment: Try changing the media type header to application/octet-stream. If the file is very huge, I think a better way to redirect the user to a normal file download service.

Comment: Thats the really hard part... i can only tell its a OutOfMemory exception because that is what shows in the output window - however, the debugger is never hit when it exceptions, but the chrome console shows the 500 server error on that request as well as the output window showing that exception

Comment: @Yuan Z What would be considered very huge? the file is 200mb

Comment: Do you get exception if you skip reading the file and just do: `new RNGCryptoServiceProvider().GetBytes(new byte[204800000]);` ?

Comment: You are using `StreamContent` which copies the file directly from disk to the network without buffering the entire file thus the size of the file on disk should not affect the amount of memory required to download the file. I would look somewhere else in your code to understand why you get this exception with large PDF files.

Comment: @Crowcoder Yes - it still exceptions.

Comment: @MartinLIversage - if i replace that same file with a smaller file it does not exception.

Comment: @99823: OK, let me rephrase my advice then: The code you have provided should not throw an `OutOfMemoryException` no matter what the size of the file is (and 200 MB is not crazy big). However, as you do get an `OutOfMemoryException` there must be something else going on in your pipeline.

Comment: I was able to pull the full exception - unfortunately not much stands out to me - but maybe you experts see something :)

Comment: 99823: The stream is getting GZip compressed and there is not enough memory to write the compressed output into a memory buffer. The compressor should be able to write the output directly to the network but for some reason it gets buffered instead.

Comment: You need to post your configuration, including gzip\deflate handlers.

Comment: Found this in startup: "config.MessageHandlers.Insert(0, new ServerCompressionHandler(new GZipCompressor(), new DeflateCompressor()));" - commented out - fixed the error!

Comment: Martin if you want to answer the question i'll select it as correct.

Comment: Well not really fixed, since gzip\deflate might be very beneficial if you download large files, and just disabling it is not very good idea,

Comment: I re-enabled in startup and added this to the web api method: [Compression(Enabled = false)] - selectively disables only per that api endpoint - but still enabled for the remaining.

Comment: Well yes, but this endpoint will benefit the most, because it returns the largest responses. Anyway from source code of this handler it seems that it for some strange reason always buffers response (which is not really necessary), so it might be the only option indeed (or you another handler which is implemented correctly).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your stack trace indicates that the exception is thrown when a `DeflateStream` is closed. This stream apparently writes to a `MemoryStream` and closing the `DeflateStream` outputs the entire (compressed) response to the `MemoryStream`. That is, the byte array buffer in the `MemoryStream` is allocated and it fails with an `OutOfMemoryException` if the compressed output is too big.

It is somewhat surprising that the compressed response is buffered in memory because a web server at least conceptually is able to stream data from a file through a compressor and to the network without having to read and compress the entire file into memory first.

From the comments I guess that you are using the NuGet package `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Extensions.Compression.Server` in your Web API application. While I can't claim that I fully understand how it works I did try to decompile it and from what I can see sending a response through this middleware results in the output being buffered not once but actually twice. (The `BaseCompressor.Compress()` method writes to a `MemoryStream` created by `StreamManager.GetStream()` and this `MemoryStream` is then read into an array of bytes effectively doubling the memory requirement of the compressor.)

Based on this analysis you should turn off compression for big responses and this seems to have fixed your problem by applying the attribute `[Compression(Enabled = false)]` to your controller action.

It is a bit ironic that you are unable to compress big responses which might benefit the most from being compressed. However, if you run your Web API on top of a web server like IIS that natively supports response compression you can completely remove the middleware and instead turn compression on in the web server (it is called [*dynamic compression*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/httpcompression/) in IIS). Native compression probably also performs better than compression done in managed code.